# How to reshape and append to Tensor inside tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to save and reload this model:

```
class VQMHA(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vqvae, mha, name=None):
        super(VQMHA, self).__init__(name=name)
        self._vqvae = vqvae
        self._vqvae.trainable = False
        self._mha = mha

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        vq_output, _ = self._vqvae.extract_features(inputs)
        flattened_features = self.flatten_features(vq_output["quantize"])
        return self._mha(flattened_features)

    def flatten_features(self, features):
        f_shape = features.shape
        # append x,y to features before squishing
        xy = np.array(
            [[[[i / f_shape[1], j / f_shape[2]] for i in range(f_shape[1])] for j in range(f_shape[2])] for _ in
             range(f_shape[0])])
        full_features = tf.concat((features, xy), axis=3)
        # squish
        new_shape = (f_shape[0], f_shape[1] * f_shape[2], f_shape[3] + 2)
        flattened_features = full_features.reshape(new_shape)
        return flattened_features

    @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 64, 64, 3], dtype=tf.float32)])
    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.__call__(inputs)
```

My understanding is that in order for a function to be usable once reloaded, it needs to be decorated with, for example:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 64, 64, 3], dtype=tf.float32)])
```

Unfortunately, I get this error (in `flatten_features`):

```
xy = np.array(

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I have tried `tf.convert_to_tensor` and `tf.constant` instead of `np.array`, but this doesn't work.

The shape of `features` depends on the inputs to build the model, so I think what's happening is that `features.shape` is something like `[None, None, None, 64]`, and as such `f_shape[0:2]` is unknown and the graph can't be built.

Does anyone know a way around this? I want to be able to modify a tensor in a function like this, save the model, then reload it and use the function.

Is there an entirely different way to save and reload a model, that doesn't require `@tf.function`?

To be clear, `flatten_features` is taking a tensor of shape `[None, 4, 4, 64]` and appending xy co-ordinates to it to make a tensor of shape `[None, 4, 4, 66]` where the x,y values (65 and 66) correspond to where the 64-length feature lies in the 4x4 grid. Then it flattens the tensor to `[None, 16, 66]`.